# Calculate CSS box height by hand

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with specific font size and line height. What is the correct mathematical formula to calculate the box height (including the padding)?

```
<div style="padding: 15px; background-color: #ccc; font-size: 18px; line-height: 1.4em;">
               text
</div>
```

Comment: Get your pencil ready.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this yet? Was my suggestion able to help you in any ways? Please share your findings

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.offsetHeight` e.g.

```
var height = document.getElementById(id_attribute_value).offsetHeight;
```

See the [HTMLElement.offsetHeight docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight) for more information

> The HTMLElement.offsetHeight read-only property is the height of the
>   element including vertical padding and borders, in pixels, as an
>   integer.

If you wish to exclude the element border, [`.innerHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight) will suffice. Also, [.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) will return a fractional value (if needed)

- note: for a jQuery solution, check out [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/), [.outerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/) and[.innerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/innerheight/)

---

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/0ws3zt40/) - demo

Comment: I am looking for a mathematic formula.

Comment: There is no formula, this is a value that represents height of the DOM element in pixels. Do you want to convert pixels to ems? What more do you expect?

Comment: @Shikkediel what do you mean by scroll bar?

Comment: @user1187968 has this helped you at all? Can you explain a bit more on what you're specifically wanting?

Comment: I just meant the value returned will also include the height of the scrollbar if present. @scniro

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do this as a mental exercise rather than using it for production. For this, you need to count the number of lines (the example is [on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/svj7j2gs/1/))

```
font-size:       18px
line-height:     1.4em = 25.2px => rounded to 25px
number of lines: 7

height (no padding)   = 25 * 7 = 175px
height (with padding) = 175 + 15 * 2 = 205
```